# Why did Lt. Vincent Hanna have his men stake out the hotel Waingro was staying at instead of the airport?

Tags: heat

In *Heat (1995)*, there was this one scene where Hanna was on the phone with his colleagues instructing them to "broadcast" Waingro's location and stake out the hotel Waingro was staying in. I understand that Hanna wants to get his man, but wouldn't his chances of catching McCauley multiply tenfold if he had his men stationed at the airport and manually verifying the identities of passengers matching McCauley's age, height, and overall description? It's almost as if Hanna was going on a wild goose chase with nothing but his gut. Throughout the film McCauley has always been portrayed as a figure who is very calculating and meticulous, a fact Nate (the crew's fence) disclosed to McCauley when the former recalled a conversation between him and a corrupt Vice sergeant.

> **Nate**: I smeared this sergeant in Vice five yards. Hanna's all over you.....
> The Vice sergeant says Hanna likes you.
> Thinks you're some kind of star. **You do this sharp, you do that sharp.**

The notion that someone like McCauley would jeopardize his chances of getting out clean for someone like Waingro is confusing to say the least

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> wouldn't his chances of catching McCauley multiply tenfold if he had his men stationed at the airport and manually verifying the identities of passengers matching McCauley's age, height, and overall description?

It would if Hanna KNEW McCauley was flying out but he doesn't. He has no idea how McCauley plans to escape. Granted flying is a possibility but that's all it is.

On the other hand Hanna's read on McCauley is that he will be compelled to kill Waingro regardless of this risk and in this assessment he is correct.

So he lets out the information so that McCauley can be trapped in a much more contained and controlled situation rather than a crowded airport terminal with potentially thousands of innocent bystanders waiting to get hit by a stray round.

> INT. HYATT HOUSE, LOBBY - SERVICE DOOR: NEIL - NIGHT
> enters and crosses to the elevators. He glances to his
> left.
>
> NEIL'S POV: DESK CLERK
> talks on his police radio. TILT DOWN. A 9mm. Beretta is
> under the counter top.
>
> NEIL
> continues to the elevators. It says he KNOWS Waingro is a
> trap. **He knows the LAPD are here. He's come for him
> anyway.**